# Apps Script to copy data up to last cell containing data in a single column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy the content of a single column and send this range of data in an email.

My users submit a for. Their email address are added in column C. I want to send a weekly email to a team member of all the email address in column C.

The number of emails in column C is increasing and decreasing daily. So I need to be able to find the number of non empty cells in column C. copy these cells and send via email using Apps Script.

Would love some help on this please!

Comment: How often are the forms submitted?

Comment: It varies. 0-10 times per day

Answer (score 1):

#### Checking for actual emails and getting a list and Sending Them

Looking at Form Response Sheet column C

Get and check the emails:

```
function getEmailAddresses() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Response Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/));
  Logger.log(vs.length);//number found
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs)); //actual emails
  return vs.join('\n');
}
```

Sending them

```
function SendWeeklyEmailList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Team Member Emails")
  const teamlist = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/)).join(',');
  GmailApp.sendEmail(teamlist,"EmailsList", getEmailAddresses())
}
```

Creating a trigger to send once every two weeks on monday near midnight

```
function createWeeklyTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'SendWeeklyEmailList').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendWeeklyEmailList').timeBased().everyWeeks(2).onWeekDay(1).atHour(0).create()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been stuck on the first part for days!

On part 2 I have a sheet called "Partner Details" where I have the email and cc of the teams I want to share the list of emails found in part 1. There are two teams.  

Setup:   

B2: Team 1 "to" address  
B3: Team 1 "cc" address  
B4: "Email subject"  
B5: "Email message with the list of emails found in part 1"  

Column C is identical data but with the Team 2 "to" and "cc" address  

So I want to send two separate emails to Team 1 (Column B) and Team 2 (Column C)

Comment: ** B5 doesn't contain the email body. But I'd like the script to add a simple message in the email body and include the emails found in part 1. For example - "Team 1, please follow up with the below contacts " [insert emails found in part 1]

Comment: *UPDATE*

Hey Cooper! Thanks so much for the help. I've managed to get everything working correctly. Huge relief. The only thing I'd like to do now is format the email so it's more readable for my partners. Currently the email body reads all one line. Is it possible to add line breaks between the intro message. "Hi there, please follow up with the below contacts" <br/>

Then is it possible to separate the list of emails we have from part 1 by line breaks? i.e email 1 <br/> email 2 <br/> etc. ?

Thanks again!!!

Comment: I added new lines